# Nash embedding for complete manifold

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I, ask my question as a comment [in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311630/nash-isometric-embedding-for-noncompact-manifolds). Without answer I post a more detailed version.

I am looking for a reference about $C^\infty$ Nash isometric embedding for non compact manifold.

My question is what are exactly the hypothesis needed on a complete manifold $M$ in order to be properly isometrically embedded into some $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I am not very interested by the optimal dimension $n$) **and** which admits a nice projection (or equivalently a tubular neighborhood of fixed width). Any modern reference will appreciated.
Thx in advance

Comment: There are two very different Nash embedding theorems; One for $C^1$ embeddings and one for $C^\infty$ embeddings. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: Good remark, I have edited the post with $C^\infty$ in fact at least $C^2$ should be good, I just want to preserve curvature...

Comment: The answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/124878/26935 shows that it is not possible in general to get a a tubular neighborhood of fixed width.

Comment: Yes, indeed I was suspected such a problem. But can I assume a lower bound on the curvature and the injectivity radius, for instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your nice projection is usually called *positive reach*.
In order to have it, one has to have both curvature bounds and a lower bound on injectivity radius.
Plus the volume growth must be at most polynomial.
Say the Lobachevsky plane does not admit a smooth embedding positive reach; see this question: [Does a Riemannian manifold with bounded geometry..](https://mathoverflow.net/q/124840).
I suspect that there are more conditions.